# what is best way to detach on a deep relationship (relationships of relationsip)?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a product which belongsToMany features which belongsToMany variants.

Product

```
public function features()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Feature::class, 'product_feature', 'product_id', 'feature_id');
}
```

Feature

```
public function variants()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Variant::class, 'feature_variant', 'feature_id', 'variant_id');
}
```

Here the **variant** relation depends on **feature** relation. If the **feature** relation is removed the related **variant** relations should be removed as well. What is the best way to do that?

I tried this

```
$product->features()->each(function($feature){
    $feature->variants()->each(function($variant){
       $variant->sync([]); // $variant()->sync([]) returns Function name must be a string in...
    });
});
```

but get `BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method App\Models\ProductFeatureVariant::sync()'`

What is the right approach here?

Comment: I guess you don't need to loop variants just do `$feature->variants()->sync([])` or `$feature->variants()->detach()` and after that same goes for product like `$product->features()->sync([])`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid that is correct. It worked using it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best id is use `cascade` and it will be what you want automaticly

```php
$table->foreign('feature')->references('id')->on('variant')->onDelete('cascade');
```

You can read more about `cascade` in this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations)

Comment: Well that is for sure a good idea and solution but I don't want to use cascade or do something implicitly. I prefer to process everything explicitly.